# Explainability and Autoencoders

Tags: lstm, autoencoder, explainable-ai

suppose I have an autoencoder as a two-stack LSTM that takes in sequences of $n$ features of some length $m$.

Let's say that the dimension of my encoding vector is $k$, so the architecture is of the form: $n \times m \to 1\times k \to n \times m$.

I'm looking into how to construct some explainability metrics on the encoding part of the autoencoder. More specifially, I'd like to know which features impact **each** of the $k$ encoding entries I have.

Naively, one could vary one feature at a time, check the impact on the encoding and see where it is greatest. This is both computationally expensive and neglects combinations of features.

Do you know of any research or methods that can assist?

Comment: Here are my thoughts, not sure any of this would work. It seems to me what you are trying to get is something like an attention mecanisms, so maybe you can have a quick look at transformer mecanisms, but as they are quite complicated, it would be more interesting to focus on something like **squeeze and excitation** layers that create some kind of weights for each map in CNN (not exactly your case, but may be close enough to apply the idea). I also heard about using PCA on the *k* space to extract human understandable ideas from it, dunno if it can help you there.

Answer (score 1):

[Feature visualization/inversion](https://distill.pub/2017/feature-visualization/) might be a good tool here. Basically, instead of performing optimization on the weights, you perform an optimization on the *inputs* that maximizes each respective entry of your encoding vector. If you want to get fancy, you might try constructing an entire [activation atlas](https://distill.pub/2019/activation-atlas/).

The [interpretml](https://github.com/interpretml/interpret) library also has a lot of good tools for model explainability, but they are more geared towards supervised models. Might still be worth checking out.